# Running Linux commands with multiple arguments

Tags: linux, go

After some digging I can run Linux commands from go like this:

```
func main() {
    lsCmd := exec.Command("ls")
    lsOut, err := lsCmd.Output()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(">ls")
    fmt.Println(string(lsOut))
}
```

What I want to do is, running following command in remote machine:

```
ssh -p $someport $someuser@$someip 'ls'
```

I can  do this successfully from my terminal, but when I try to run it within Go, I get following error:

```
panic: exec: "ssh -p $someport $someuser@$someip 'ls'": executable file not found in $PATH
```

**Update**: I updated the question for convenience.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the doc about the [exec](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command) package, program name and arguments are differents parameters of the `Command` method.
You should do something like that :

```
exec.Command("ssh", "-p port", "user@ip", "'ls'")
```

If you need something more elaborate, you could also look at the [go.crypto/ssh](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.crypto/ssh) package.

Answer (score -1):

If you want run multiple commands on a remote machine the below trick might help you achieve this.

```
Ssh username@ip < EOf

ls -I

Pwd

Uname

Eof
```

Please note that it doesn't pass any special characters like `. ,` etc.